# Need help deserializing dictionary Json in WPF

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, deserialization

I'm trying to parse a Json string and put a section into a dictionary. I'm running into a problem where trying to deserialize into a dictionary expects "key" and "value" terms, which are unavailable to me. Can anyone recommend a workaround for me please? I prefer to stick to DataContractJsonSerializer if possible. Thank you very much in advance.

{
  "boxes": 2,
  "box": [
    {
      "apples": "6",
      "bananas": "3",
      "oranges": "4",
      "lemons": "2"
    },
    {
      "peaches": "4",
      "limes": "5",
      "melons": "5",
      "apples": "2"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking into [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). It's a fully featured and robust library that is the best way (in my opinion) to handle JSON in any .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a JSON serialization library shipped with C# driver for MongoDB. You can start reading about it [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fast and lightweight [ServiceStack's Json Serializer](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/text-serializers/json-serializer) to handle this for you, it allows you to deserialize strongly-typed POCO's or dynamically using JsonObject:

#### Using Strong-Typed POCO

```
var fruitsJson = "{ \"boxes\": 2, \"box\": [ { \"apples\": \"6\", \"bananas\": \"3\", \"oranges\": \"4\", \"lemons\": \"2\" }, { \"peaches\": \"4\", \"limes\": \"5\", \"melons\": \"5\", \"apples\": \"2\" } ] }";

public class Fruits
{
    public int boxes { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string,string>> box { get; set; }
}

var fruits = fruitsJson.FromJson<Fruits>();
```

#### Dynamically using JsonObject

```
var jsonObj = JsonObject.Parse(fruitsJson);
var boxes = jsonObj["boxes"];
var box = jsonObj["box"].FromJson<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>();
```